# Android saving to external SD card?

Tags: java, android, sd-card

Why I cannot save this file to the external sd? Can you check over my code?

```
 public void Download()
  {
      try {
            //this is the file you want to download from the remote server
            String path ="http://mozilla.cdn.leaseweb.com/firefox/releases/4.0.1/win32/en-US/Firefox%20Setup%204.0.1.exe";
            //this is the name of the local file you will create
            String targetFileName;
                boolean eof = false;
            URL u = new URL(path);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();
            
            //String svto = Environment.getExternalStorageState().toString();
            File path1 = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

            path1.mkdirs();
            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File(path1+"/fox.exe"));
                InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len1 = 0;
                while ( (len1 = in.read(buffer)) !=  -1 ) {
                f.write(buffer,0, len1);
                         }
            f.close();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

  }
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: It would be good to see the error and/or stack trace in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This operation will fail if you don't have the following permissions in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Make sure to put them within the top-level `<manifest>` tag, not the `<application>` tag where your activities are specified.

Comment: And android.permission.INTERNET as well

Comment: I had already added those, still not able to get it to go to the external. I can save the file to data/data but then users cant access it.

Comment: OMG got it, when i was moving the premissions in the manifest i accidently deleted 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem similar to this before. It turned out that I had to manually create the directory first on the SD card before calling code such as `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);`

Check if the absolute path exists on your file explorer for that directory. If it doesn't, then create it via `adb shell` and then give it a try again. This solved my problem, but it may not necessarily solve yours, give it a try though!

Comment: That is how im doing it, still does not seem to work =/. And im testing on both my phone and emulator, same result.