# Android how to move Media pictures to another folder?

Tags: android, sd-card

In my android application i want to copy the media images to another folder(in my below code i try to copy picture from "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/my_photo.jpg" to "/mnt/sdcard/PortFolio/MyGallery/ . I tried this with the following code but it doesn't work. Someone help me out of this??? Is there any other way possible??

```
File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
            if (sd.canWrite()) {
                String sourceImagePath= "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/my_photo.jpg";
                String destinationImagePath= "/mnt/sdcard/PortFolio/MyGallery/";
                Log.d("destinationImagePath", ""+destinationImagePath);
                File source= new File(data, sourceImagePath);
                File destination= new File(sd, destinationImagePath);
                Log.d("before copying", "");
                if (source.exists()) {
                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(destination).getChannel();
                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                    src.close();
                    dst.close();
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sd` already contains `/mnt/sdcard`. You are actually trying to open `/mnt/sdcard/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/my_photo.jpg`. Remove `/mnt/sdcard` from `sourceImagePath` and `destinationImagePath`. You would probably also need to [create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130932/how-to-create-directory-automatically-on-sd-card) the `PortFolio/MyGallery` folder first.

Starting API level 8, you can also use this to get the default pictures folder:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```

And last but not least, make sure you [have permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837300/android-saving-to-external-sd-card) to access the SD card.