# Having pic from gallery to save in my app as a profile pic - E.g. Contact picture in Phonebook

Tags: android

I am working on an app where it has user's name, email etc along with their pic. I am able to have a function where if the user clicks on a image button, it will as them if they want to use camera or upload it from their Gallery. Everything works fine from here. Once they select the pic , i want the imagebutton to have the pic they selected/capture even if they go to another page..something like the contact picture in phonebook. 
As of right now, my images taken from camera saves as Image(int)+date. Is there a way to have the pic that user upload.capture to show at all time. 
I tried searching everywhere and they all show the method where you can select the image and view it but doesn't not save it. If the app restarts or moves to another page. the pic disappears. Please Help

Comment: I have an idea, why not move the selected image to a catch directory and use SharedPreference http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html to store image URI to show it in the ImageView.

Comment: thanks for the reply..i am new to this . DO you have an example. I know about SharedPreference but was told that it is not good idea to use it for pic. I am not sure about catch directory and how to work with it. Would you please be able to give me some example. Thanks

Comment: check my answer. and accept it please if you find it useful

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of moving image to a directory that you want (catch) [Android how to move Media pictures to another folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326878/android-how-to-move-media-pictures-to-another-folder) and use SharedPerference to store the image path. and each time user open the Activity that has the image it should stream the image using the image path stored in the SharedPerference, don't forget to use `exist()` to check if the file exist otherwise you should show a default image.

**why we should use an alternative place to store image?**
because the user may remove the image or move it to other place. 
**where should I move the image ?** 
to any place in device memory, and DO NOT save the image with it original extension, because it will show up in the user's gallery and that may annoy the user.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Catching is something good to know. However my images are stored correctly. The problem is how to get them showing all the time. I am familiar with saving edit text(string)in to shared preference but not sure how to go about with shared preference. do you have a link that could show or provide me with some more info.pls and thnx

Comment: when a user successfully select an image you should store in SharedPreference the image path of selected image, e.g:`sdcard/Camera/my_photo.jpg`.in the activity check if that value is null or not, if it's not null then stream the path stored in PS and use `setImageBitmap` to show the image in the ImageView you want.

Comment: Sorry to keep asking.I have set my pics to save by adding 1 digit everytime user saves an image. Do you have sample of how you can call shared preference path and apply it on Imageview.Really appreciate your help on this.